# Map top level array of strings with RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm finding it difficult to deal with a webservice that has a top level array with no keypath and the array contains only strings, i.e.:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

It would be easy to map if it were something like:

```
{"array_of_strings": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]}
```

I thought perhaps having a nil keyPath and mappingForClass:[NSString class] might do the trick, but it didn't seem to (I'm not sure that mapping for NSString even makes sense, but thought it might be a special case RestKit could handle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a nil key path, but you're expected to map into an object where the string is an attribute. Something like:

```
RKEntityMapping *objectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:...];
[objectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"name"]];
objectMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"name" ];
```

If you just want to map into an array of strings then you don't need RestKit and you should just use `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

Comment: Ah good call, I was doing the rest of my web services requests with RestKit and didn't even think to just use AFNetworking for this simple request. Great point.